# syncfusion ejchart - sync 2 charts

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, charts, syncfusion

Am discovering Syncfusion and that's look pretty cool. But, I am wondering if it's possible to show programatically a trackball on a chart ?
In fact, I would like to show a trackball line on a second chart when I select a point on the first chart.

Here is my asp.net mvc 5 code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Chart 1</h2><br />
        <div id="ControlRegion">
            <div id="Tooltip" style="display: none;">
                <div id="icon">
                    <div id="eficon"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="value">
                    <div>
                        <label id="efpercentage">#point.y#</label><br />
                        <label id="ef">Efficiency</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @(Html.EJ().Chart("container1")
                       .PrimaryXAxis(pr => pr.Range(ra => ra.Min(2005).Max(2011).Interval(1)).Title(tl => tl.Text("Year")))
                       .PrimaryYAxis(pr => pr.Title(tl => tl.Text("Efficiency")).RangePadding(ChartRangePadding.None).LabelFormat("{value}%").Range(ra => ra.Min(25).Max(50).Interval(5)))
                       .CommonSeriesOptions(cr => cr.Type(SeriesType.Line).EnableAnimation(true).Marker(mr => mr.Shape(ChartShape.Circle).Size(sz => sz.Height(10).Width(10)).Visible(true)).Tooltip(sr1 => sr1.Visible(false).Template("Tooltip")).Border(st => st.Width(2)))
                       .Series(sr =>
                           {
                               sr.Points(pt =>
                                   {
                                       pt.X("2005").Y(28).Add();
                                       pt.X("2006").Y(25).Add();
                                       pt.X("2007").Y(26).Add();
                                       pt.X("2008").Y(27).Add();
                                       pt.X("2009").Y(32).Add();
                                       pt.X("2010").Y(35).Add();
                                       pt.X("2011").Y(30).Add();
                                   })
                                   .Name("India")
                                   .SelectionSettings(ss => ss.Enable(true).Mode(ChartMode.Point).Pattern(ChartPattern.Circle).Type(ChartSelectionType.Single))
                                   .Add();
                           })
                       .Axes(ax =>
                         {
                             ax.MajorGridLines(mj => mj.Visible(false)).CrosshairLabel(chAxes => chAxes.Visible(true)).Orientation("Horizontal").Name("xAxis1").ValueType(AxisValueType.Datetime).LabelRotation(90).Add();
                             ax.MajorGridLines(mj => mj.Visible(false)).LabelFormat("{value}mm").CrosshairLabel(seAxes => seAxes.Visible(true)).Orientation("Vertical").OpposedPosition(true).Range(rg => rg.Min(0).Max(150).Interval(20)).Name("yAxis").Add();
                         })
                       .Crosshair(cr => cr.Visible(true).Type(CrosshairType.Trackball))
                       .Zooming(zn => zn.Enable(false).EnableMouseWheel(false))
                       .CanResize(true)
                       .Load("loadTheme")
                       .Title(title => title.Text("Efficiency of oil-fired power production"))
                       .Size(sz => sz.Height("600"))
                       .SeriesRegionClick("seriesSelection")
                       .Legend(lg => { lg.Visible(true); }))
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Chart 2</h2><br />
        <div id="ControlRegion2">
            <div id="Tooltip" style="display: none;">
                <div id="icon2">
                    <div id="eficon2"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="value2">
                    <div>
                        <label id="efpercentage2">#point.y#</label><br />
                        <label id="ef2">Efficiency</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @(Html.EJ().Chart("container2")
                       .PrimaryXAxis(pr => pr.Range(ra => ra.Min(2005).Max(2011).Interval(1)).Title(tl => tl.Text("Year")))
                       .PrimaryYAxis(pr => pr.Title(tl => tl.Text("Efficiency")).RangePadding(ChartRangePadding.None).LabelFormat("{value}%").Range(ra => ra.Min(25).Max(50).Interval(5)))
                       .CommonSeriesOptions(cr => cr.Type(SeriesType.Line).EnableAnimation(true).Marker(mr => mr.Shape(ChartShape.Circle).Size(sz => sz.Height(10).Width(10)).Visible(true)).Tooltip(sr1 => sr1.Visible(false).Template("Tooltip")).Border(st => st.Width(2)))
                       .Series(sr =>
                           {
                               sr.Points(pt =>
                                   {
                                       pt.X("2005").Y(28).Add();
                                       pt.X("2006").Y(25).Add();
                                       pt.X("2007").Y(26).Add();
                                       pt.X("2008").Y(27).Add();
                                       pt.X("2009").Y(32).Add();
                                       pt.X("2010").Y(35).Add();
                                       pt.X("2011").Y(30).Add();
                                   })
                                   .Name("India")
                                   .SelectionSettings(ss => ss.Enable(true).Mode(ChartMode.Point).Pattern(ChartPattern.Circle).Type(ChartSelectionType.Single))
                                   .Add();
                           })
                       .Axes(ax =>
                         {
                             ax.MajorGridLines(mj => mj.Visible(false)).CrosshairLabel(chAxes => chAxes.Visible(true)).Orientation("Horizontal").Name("xAxis1").ValueType(AxisValueType.Datetime).LabelRotation(90).Add();
                             ax.MajorGridLines(mj => mj.Visible(false)).LabelFormat("{value}mm").CrosshairLabel(seAxes => seAxes.Visible(true)).Orientation("Vertical").OpposedPosition(true).Range(rg => rg.Min(0).Max(150).Interval(20)).Name("yAxis").Add();
                         })
                       .Crosshair(cr => cr.Visible(true).Type(CrosshairType.Trackball))
                       .Zooming(zn => zn.Enable(false).EnableMouseWheel(false))
                       .CanResize(true)
                       .Load("loadTheme")
                       .Title(title => title.Text("Efficiency of oil-fired power production"))
                       .Size(sz => sz.Height("600"))
                       .Legend(lg => { lg.Visible(true); }))
        </div>
    </div>
    <style class="cssStyles">
        .tooltipDiv {
            background-color: #E94649;
            color: white;
            width: 130px;
        }

        #Tooltip > div:first-child {
            float: left;
        }

        #Tooltip #value {
            float: right;
            height: 50px;
            width: 63px;
        }

            #Tooltip #value > div {
                margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            }

        #Tooltip #efpercentage {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: segoe ui;
        }

        #Tooltip #ef {
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: segoe ui;
        }

        #eficon {
            background-image: url("../Content/Images/Chart/eficon.png");
            height: 60px;
            width: 60px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

and my JS function that only select the point on the 2nd chart :

```
   function seriesSelection(sender) {
        $("#container2").ejChart({
            selectedDataPointIndexes: sender.selectedData
        });
    }
```

Is there any way to show a line on `#container2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amazing support team answered [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/135859/syncfusion-ejchart-sync-2-charts)

By the way, here is my implementation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart2_ID = "container2";

    function mouseMove(sender) { 
        var targertChart = $("#" + chart2_ID).ejChart("instance"); 
        targertChart.mousemoveX = sender.data.location.x, targertChart.mousemoveY = sender.data.location.y; 
        targertChart.chartTrackball(targertChart, sender.data.location); 
    } 

</script>
```